# Entity Framework: Unable to add a record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am new to C# development and I am trying to write something that can insert a record in a DB. I have a simple test, which I hoped would insert a record into the database when I run it.

Model:

```cs
namespace Users.Models;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class User
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string HashedPassword { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Test:

```cs
namespace Database.Tests;

using Users.Models;
using Xunit;

public class ReferrerTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestInsert()
    {
        User user = new()
        {
            Name = "Bob",
            EmailAddress = "bob@email.com",
            HashedPassword = "hgfj",
        };

        using MyDbContext ctx = new();
        ctx.Users.Add(user);
    }
}
```

Database context:

```cs
namespace Database;

using Users.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using Npgsql;

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(Config))]
[SuppressDbSetInitialization]
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(): base(MakeConnString()) {}

    private static string MakeConnString()
    {
        // Will be moving these to a common location
        string OptEnv(string key, string default_) =>
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(key) ?? default_;

        string Env(string key) =>
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(key) ?? throw new MissingFieldException(key);

        NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new()
        {
            Host = Env("PGHOST"),
            Port = int.Parse(OptEnv("PGPORT", "5432")),
            SslMode = Enum.Parse<SslMode>(OptEnv("PGSSLMODE", "Require")),
            TrustServerCertificate = true,
            Database = OptEnv("PGDATABASE", "postgres"),
            Username = OptEnv("PGUSER", "postgres"),
            Password = Env("PGPASSWORD")
        };
        return builder.ConnectionString;
    }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

When running this code I get:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I think I must have something that is preventing the mapping to my database, but I have been unable to figure it out.

#### EDIT

I think it's probably important I show the DDL of the table as well:

```sql
create table public.user
(
    id            integer generated always as identity primary key,
    name          text                                               not null
        constraint user_name_check
            check (length(name) > 0),
    email_address text                                               not null unique
        constraint user_email_address_check
            check (email_address ~* '^.+@.+\..+$'),
    -- Ideally use something like 
    -- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/pgcrypto.html
    hash_password text                                               not null
        constraint user_password_hash_check
            check (length(password_hash) > 0),
    created       timestamp with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null
        constraint user_created_check
            check (created <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
);

alter table public."user"
    owner to postgres;
```

##### EDIT 2:

Suggestions to use annotations to try to get the model to map directly to the DDL - still gives the same error, but this is our new model.

```cs
namespace Users.Models;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


[Table("user", Schema="public")]
public class User
{ 
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [Column("email_address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    
    [Column("hash_password")]
    public string HashedPassword { get; set; }
    
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [Column("created")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints and debugging into your app to find out exactly which item is null?  That is usually my first approach to solve issues like this.

Comment: Also that error should give you a line number which should help narrow down the spot of the error without even having to debug.

Comment: Yeah, but when I try to step into `Add` I loose the stack.

Comment: Yes, the offending line is `ctx.Users.Add(user);`

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on my EFC, but your 'Users' property in your DbContext is null, doesn't get initialized, so your db doesn't have the Users table, or as you said can't map onto it. I don't know how to fix that I'm afraid, but just in case you don't get an answer on this question, should give you a hand when googling.

Comment: @DubDub this is helpful thanks. 

I have edited my Q with the DDL of the table as well. I think there is a few issues, one being mapping to the snake-cased columns and another being this nullable `Users`

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense, try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#column-names using the DataAnnotation you can define the exact column name on the properties of your User object

Comment: @DubDub see edit 2. Same error :(

Comment: Why is your Users property virtual? Not sure if that's the issue, can't see why it would be, but might be worth removing it and seeing if that works.

Comment: @DubDub no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243828/discussion-between-dubdub-and-bob).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your DB but your model requires the Id column to have a value (it's not nullable) So you need to proivde a value in order to do that.

If your Id column type is Serial on the DB side, just decorate your Id column with :

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @DubDub advice, removing the following line fixed it:

```cs
[SuppressDbSetInitialization]
```